# Are chests in your children's bedroom safe or do they respawn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just adopted a child in Skyrim, and they're staying in the second bedroom in Breezehome (your house in Whiterun). They left me a few items in the chest, but I'm wondering if it's possible for them to steal back (or randomly disappear) items that are left in that chest. In other words, is the chest in the second bedroom "safe" if I store items, or should I always store them upstairs, in the master bedroom?

Comment: npcs in skyrim will never interact with chests to take stuff afaik.  and all containers in your own house should be safe...

Comment: @spartacus That wasn't necessarily true in Oblivion, I don't know if you can say the same about Skyrim either.

Comment: @Spartacus:  I know for a fact that NPCs will at least take things from unsafe containers.  I use the barrels in Riverwood for all my storage.  One time, I was curious about this blizzard scroll, so I used it and ended up agro'ing everyone in the whole town who was within its blast radius.  Gerdur runs to my weapons barrel, pulls out a war hammer, and comes at me with it bro-style.  I don't know if this would happen with protected containers, though.

Answer (score 1):

It heavily depends on the house, and what specific containers. Breezehome in specific is safe.  You can check this link: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Breezehome for the status of different houses, in regards to chest and container safety. This specific house does not have re-spawn containers, so it is safe.

Comment: Your answer suggests that some in some other houses, chests in the children's bedrooms are _not_ save. But you don't say so explicitly, and the wiki you linked doesn't mention it. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

All containers in your house are safe, even childrens containers since they are part of your house. You don't need to worry about any container in your house. They're all safe since the house is yours.